# What is the meaning of $\Bbb R^{2+}$ in this formula

Tags: notation

What is the meaning of $\Bbb R^{2+}$ in this formula?
$$\Gamma_1=\{(z_1,z_2)\in\Bbb R^{2+}:z_1\ge z_2\}$$

Comment: It's not standard notation. It could be $\mathbb{R}^+\times \mathbb{R}^+$.

Comment: My guess is that the $+$ notes, that you only observe positive real numbers. Hence $z_1\geq z_2>0$.

Comment: Probably the set of pairs of positive real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Given that

- $\Bbb R^2$ is the space of ordered pairs of real numbers
- $\Bbb R^+$ are the positive real numbers

I would say that $\Bbb R^{2+}$ is the set of ordered pairs of positive real numbers, although the notation is non-standard.